Define the JSON stracture - its hierarchy from pyspark Dataframe value
Im wondering if its possible to define the structure of the JSON type kind values inside my dataframe.
So I have a dataframe which has the nested JSON type values per row. As its shown in the below image.

I would like to define the structure of the dict inside (note that actual value dtype in databricks table is string).
I want to wrtie a code which will give me something like this (this was achived with below code by me) 
I have managed to do the simialr thing when Im reading the JSON file itself with the below code but Im not able to do the same to my dataframe. Any help would be appraiated.
df = spark.read.json('abfss://bronze@path.dfs.core.windows.net/json_flatten/*.json', multiLine= True)
schema = df.schema
 
def print_schema_levels(schema, level=1):
    indent = "    " * (level - 1)
    for field in schema.fields:
        print(f"{indent}Level {level}: {field.name} ({type(field.dataType).__name__})")
        if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
            print_schema_levels(field.dataType, level + 1)
        elif isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType) and isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, StructType):
            print_schema_levels(field.dataType.elementType, level + 1)
 
print_schema_levels(schema)


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78292935/3238085  This answer can help you.

Please add the json sample in the question.

Is it string type inside your dataframe?

yes, its string.

Below are the ways you can parse a JSON string in a DataFrame column.
If the JSON string in all rows is in a standard format and has common fields, use the following code to parse:
Get the first row data and use that for creating a schema.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, schema_of_json

data = [
    ('{"id":1,"name":"John","address":{"street":"123 Main St","city":"Anytown","state":"CA","postal_code":"12345"},"orders":[{"order_id":100,"date":"2023-01-01","items":[{"product_id":"A1","quantity":2,"price":10.0},{"product_id":"B2","quantity":1,"price":20.0}]},{"order_id":101,"date":"2023-01-10","items":[{"product_id":"A1","quantity":1,"price":10.0}]}]}',)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["json_column"])

dt = df.collect()[0][0]
df.withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("json_column"), schema_of_json(dt))).printSchema()

In the second case, if you have different fields among DataFrame rows, create a standard schema that you need and then parse it.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, schema_of_json

data = [
    ('{"id":1,"name":"John","address":{"street":"123 Main St","city":"Anytown","state":"CA","postal_code":"12345"},"orders":[{"order_id":100,"date":"2023-01-01","items":[{"product_id":"A1","quantity":2,"price":10.0},{"product_id":"B2","quantity":1,"price":20.0}]},{"order_id":101,"date":"2023-01-10","items":[{"product_id":"A1","quantity":1,"price":10.0}]}]}',)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["json_column"])

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType, FloatType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("address", StructType([
        StructField("street", StringType(), True),
        StructField("city", StringType(), True),
        StructField("state", StringType(), True),
        StructField("postal_code", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("orders", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("order_id", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("date", StringType(), True),
        StructField("items", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("product_id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("quantity", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("price", FloatType(), True)
        ]), True))
    ]), True))
])

df.withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("json_column"), schema)).printSchema()

Output:

